# Не получается вытащить запись из БД PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, php7

Есть страница, в которой надо вывести данные из БД. Я подключил PDO, написал код, однако как результат никаких данных не ввелось.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'marlintask';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt); 

 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT justName FROM staff_data WHERE id = 2');
$stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY))
  {
    echo $row[0] . "\n";
    echo $row['justName'] . "\n";
    echo $row->justName . "\n";
};      
?>
```

Comment: Так как экстрасенсов здесь не очень много, лучше добавить в вопрос лог ошибок.

Comment: И смысл передавать `[$_GET['id']]` в `execute`?

Comment: @Ivan Dudarev я вроде как включил ошибки, когда они были, выводились, а сейчас ничего нет

Comment: @u_mulder Без него ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ничего не работает, то надо отлаживаться.

Но сначала надо писать осмысленный код. Для этого

- во-первых, определиться, выполняем мы одготовленный запрос, или нет
- во-вторых, сообразить что режим PDO::FETCH_LAZY нам здесь нужен как рыбке зонтик, как и цикл вообще
- а нужен метод fetchColumn()

поэтому переписываем код

```
// проверяем со статическим запросом
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT justName FROM staff_data WHERE id = 2');
$row = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($row);

// проверяем с переменной
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT justName FROM staff_data WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->execute([$_GET['id']]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($row, $_GET['id']);

// смотрим есть ли у нас вообще в базе что-нибудь
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, justName FROM staff_data ORDER BY id LIMIT 5');
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($data);
```

после этого смотрим что выводит и корректируем своиожидания

Comment: 1) Проверка со статическим запросом вернула array(1) { ["justName"]=> string(3) "Jos" }   и это великолепно, он вернул значение из БД.
2) Проверка с переменной вернула bool(false) NULL, не совсем понимаю почему.
3) array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["justName"]=> string(5) "Sunny" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["justName"]=> string(3) "Jos" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["justName"]=> string(7) "Jovanni" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["justName"]=> string(7) "Roberto" } } вернула вполне правильный ответ) спасибо)

Comment: проверка с динамической переменной очевидным образом  означает что в $_GET['id'] лежит тыква. Другими словами этой переменной на момент выполнения скрипта не существует, и к ПДО проблема никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: Понял. Огромное спасибо. Я начинающий и третий день не мог с этим разобраться.

Comment: Надо чтобы всегда был уровень отображения ошибок E_ALL. Тогда РНР сам бы сказал что такой переменной нету